# How to properly type function that calls another function and passes variable number of arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So here is the situation. In my app I want to create a generic function that allows me to reuse some common logic.

I want to keep a configuration file like this:

```
const configs = {
    getSomething: {
        transformer: (): SomeType => ({ some: 'type' }),
        getUrl: () => '/some/path'
    },
    deleteSomething: {
        transformer: (): SomeOtherType => ({ other: 'sometype' }),
        getUrl: (id: string) => `/some/${id}other/path`
    }
}
```

Then, in the reusable function (below), I'm not able to properly type the `getUrl` call. Here is what it looks like in plain JS:

```
export function doSomethingGeneric(accessor, params) {
    const config = configs[accessor]

    return config.getUrl(...params)
}
```

This is a trimmed down version for the sake of the question. I was able to successfully type the generic function to return `SomeType` or `SomeOtherType` based on the value of the `accessor`. I thought I could use the same concept for `getUrl`, but this does not work:

```
type Configs = typeof configs
type Keys = keyof Configs
export function doSomethingGeneric<
    A extends Keys,
    Params extends Parameters<Configs[A]['getUrl']>
>(accessor: A, params: Params) {
    const config = configs[accessor]

    return config.getUrl(...params)
}
```

I get an error on `(...params)` in the return statement with the following message:

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.
```

How would you guys go about solving this one? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like [this again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60368369/2887218)... review that answer and see if this works for you.  Basically the compiler won't be able to understand this sort of correlation.  You'll need to do an assertion or redundant code.

Comment: For example, [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzCMC8MDeBYAUDDCgKZQDKIAtmQBZJgoBcOBRRUATgIaQIicanFgAoAlJgB8MEdhgRqJFgHIoATwAOJZTAC+YgDRt2pKAFVOAG1ESM05QHoFNBxu5Ray47qOEYAExJLMhJKGg8GZlY-Dh4+ASEbKRk5EA8SYRhlZzJNbT1DYyJTC2sZJH8WaE5I22kAAydFBwASbArdNNoM13daeu8CXQICdS0YAGFwZDRMGDGSEAQ4adQIUbyYAGkSNXQsAGtdpcnVtBH8EgAPDQFYBABXMGAoJHAAkDC6SIBxEjAMkhgAAeACCMGuUH+-nQOz2khExm4wGAJAgCkyoN8RDcPCoEBYAAVuHiQpwIMCpog1gBtUEAXRpyhKVmU9MkBAkeD88GgK2pKDm8BmEBpyNR6IE9Jg3HQvDUMvQchZlhEADoNRoWAsTrjuPixCwAEpkB6cMAAFTylLOooZTJVbOkugA3MZOKbzfyZmqVerNST9RAxEMgA) assertion

Comment: It did the trick, thank you very much!